# Enabled memcached Plugin on mysql

Tags: mysql, memcached

i've installed mysql5.6 on debian 8 , i've also enabled daemon_memcached. After enabled memcached i restart mysql , but when i type netstat -tnpl i didn't see mysql listen on port 11211 ??

```
mysql-apt-config0.6.0-1
mysql-client              5.6.29-1debian8
mysql-common              5.6.29-1debian8
mysql-community-client    5.6.29-1debian8
mysql-community-server    5.6.29-1debian8
mysql-server              5.6.29-1debian8
mysql-server-             5.55.5.46-0+deb8u1
mysql-server-             5.65.6.28-1
```

My question is do i need to install the application memcache ?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached-troubleshoot.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a a bug in mysql 5.6.21 for use the feature memcached.
you must to download the 5.7.11 for use the feature i tried it and it's working ;)